# jquery .click() does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-click-event, jquery-trigger

on my php page I want to click a button on page load.
I have tested it with jQuery and JS.
While jQuery does not work, the JS works fine.

Any idea why this is the case?

jQuery:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#button_id').click();
    $('#button_id').trigger('click');
});
</script>
```

JS:

```
<script>
    window.onload = function() {
        document.getElementById('button_id').click();
    };
</script>
```

The button I want to click has a `data-filter` inside. Might this be the problem?

```
<button id="button_id" data-filter=".parkett" class="sub">Button</button>
```

EDIT:

No errors in the console, libary is added at the top.

This is my console output if I log both buttons:

[Screenshot of console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/47oKo.png)

Comment: When you say "jQuery does not work" why? does it have an unexpected behavior? Is there any error message? is it just not doing anything at all?

Comment: Check your console for errors.

Comment: Do you have the jquery library added?

Comment: @Phiter please see the update on my question. For me it looks like the button is indeed found but the click() action is not performed

Comment: Can you reproduce this on jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("document").ready(function() {
setTimeout(function() {
    $("#button_id").trigger('click');
},10);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

> $('#button_id').click();

You have defined no click handler - so nothing going to happen. You need to drop a function in there to use as the callback. Like this:

```
 $( "#button_id" ).click(function() {
    $(this).trigger('click');
 });
```

Answer (score -2):

Sounds like you haven't included the jquery script in your head

```
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

Comment: libary is added in head. Please see my edited question. Thanks

Comment: Your jquery script should look like this:
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#button_id').click(function(){
//Event to be triggered on click.
});
});
</script>